# map .NET types to SQL Server 200 data types

Tags: sql-server-2008, types

How can I store a .NET double in an SQL Server 2008 data type?

I get an exception 'Parameter value '1.3465492655247000' is out of range' when I try to store a double in a numeric(16, 16) column. Because the number has 16 decimal place and a 1 in front. numeric(16.16) is the maximum i can set in SQL Server for that type.

I created an ADO.NET dataset in C# and there the column is set as decimal. 
I cast the double to a decimal.

This [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) shows the SQL Server 2008 data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numeric(16, 16)` allows a number of length 16 with all 16 digits reserved for the digits after the decimal point.

You can go up to `numeric(38, 16)`. This will allow up to 22 digits to the left of the decimal point and 16 to the right.

This doesn't quite allow the full range of [`±1.0 × 10^28 to ±7.9 × 10^28`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx). If you need numbers that large you would need to reduce the amount of digits reserved for decimal places.

Comment: [SQL Server Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)